# Why For cycle, changes the tuple values (Python)

Tags: python, tuples

I have the following code:

---

`meses=('Enero','Febrero','Marzo','Abril','Mayo','Junio','Julio','Agosto','Septiembre','Octubre','Noviembre','Diciembre')
    for meses in meses:
        print("- ",meses)
    print (meses)`

After the iteration, the tuple now only have one value: Diciembre
I have tried Enumerate, and works pretty well, but I'd like to know, what's happening with the For cycle, why changes the size of the tuple?.

Comment: In `for meses in meses` both the tuple and the loop variable have the same name.

Comment: messes is a variable and each iteration you assign it a different value. At the end you can see the last assigned value.

Comment: Thank you very much, for the fast and clear reply! @DimKoim

Answer (score 2):

You have the same name for looping variable and the list name. So basically `meses` is the looping variable holding the last value of the original list `meses`.

Comment: Simple and it could be a very nice example of what to avoid, while working with tuples!